# iTunes not recognizing music from NAS

Tags: itunes, network-shares, nas, libraries

At the current moment I have a SONOS system running through my house. The SONOS takes music directly from a NAS. I want to be able to get iTunes to be able to play music from the NAS without copying them to my local drive. At the moment, the iTunes has been able to recognise the NAS, but it is reading the music from a file within the NAS called Qmultimedia. All of my music is inside a "music" folder that SONOS is using.

Comment: Are you running window's or mac ? or linux with a windows/mac VM to get iTunes running ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to install something like firefly on the NAS:
http://wiki.fireflymediaserver.org/

Or set up an smb share on the NAS to share the music dir and set that as the media directory for itunes